# Pyspark dataframe strange behaviour

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark, databricks

I have an issue with pyspark df. df has around 300k rows. when running `display()` in databricks or `show()` in vscode theres no problem
and will display data.

However, as soon as there's `df.select("col1")`, vscode execution automatically terminates with no error message or exception raised. The code and cluster are exactly the same.

Any idea on how to debug or if its a known reason in vscode and number of lines?

Comment: what operation(s) are you performing on `df.select("col1")`?

Comment: 1st declare df = none
2nd assign df = df1.join(df2)
3rd df.show()
Note: df1 and df2 are not empty and have records, show() also works
thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: Could it be that name `col1` becomes not unique after the join? Did you try to qualify it?

Answer (score 0):

Initial post:
"1st declare df = none
2nd assign df = df1.join(df2)
3rd df.show() Note: df1 and df2 are not empty and have records, show() also works"
Answer: The issue was on step 2.
On df2 I created empty columns with None/'N/A' (for later use)
These columns already existed in df1 with values.
Even though these columns were not selected during the join, pyspark was not accepting the function well/ hence it would exit the run, but without any error/exception.
Unclear why it worked on databricks but not on vscode.
For anyone stumbling on this query, try to delete the uncessary columns and only add where needed.
Thank you for all the answers